# libssh2 in Windows using Qt Creator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, libcurl, libssh2

I'm trying to build a Qt project which uses cUrl in Windows. I've managed to successfully link my project with libcUrl.

I'm using Qt Creator 3.5.1, Qt 5.5.1, with compiler MinGW 4.9.2 32 bit.

Here is my main.cpp (yes, I know I'm missing global cleanup, I'm only trying to get it to compile at the moment):

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

To get libcUrl working, I've added the following to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\include
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DCURL_STATICLIB
LIBS += C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a
```

Note, adding the -DCURL_STATICLIB resolved errors I had before where I got the undefined reference:

```
C:\...\main.cpp:7: error: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
```

However now I get the following undefined refences:

```
C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(easy.o):-1: error: undefined reference to `libssh2_init'
C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(easy.o):-1: error: undefined reference to `libssh2_exit'
:-1: error: C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(easy.o): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.data'
collect2.exe:-1: error: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I guess I'm missing ssh2. How can I include that? What other dependencies will come up after this one also?

EDIT: Added `LIBS += -lws2_32` to the .pro file. This removed the following 3 errors.

```
C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(easy.o):-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(easy.o):-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'
C:\Libs\C\curl-7.45.0-win32-mingw\lib\libcurl.a(easy.o):-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a monstrous pain.

I ended up downloading the source of libcurl, rebuilding without ssh2, and then by including `-lwldap32` also, I finally got it to build without error.

However code that succeeds in Linux fails in Windows.